# How to set a same domain cookie with Heroku subdomains?

Tags: javascript, heroku, cookies, cross-domain, subdomain

I have my front end running on one Heroku instance: `fe.herokuapp.com`

And my back end running on another instance: `be.herokuapp.com`

I want to set a **same domain** cookie when a user logs in from the front end.

I am using Koa cookies module to set the cookie like so:

```
cookies.set("accessToken", token, {
  maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 24,
  signed: true,
  secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
  httpOnly: true,
  domain: process.env.ORIGIN_HOSTNAME || "localhost"
})
```

If it helps, I'm using a React front end and a Node back end (using Koa).

Via Postman, my back end returns the following set-cookie header:

```
accessToken=<access_token>; path=/; expires=Sun, 01 Sep 2019 16:27:24 GMT; domain=.herokuapp.com; secure; httponly
```

However, via my React app, I can't see any set-cookie headers.

My front end is using `isomorphic-unfetch` library with `credentials = "include"`. (perhaps this needs to be `same-origin` since it's on the same subdomain?)

My two questions are:

1. Why can't I set the domain value in my cookie from the back end to be `fe.herokuapp.com`?
2. Why can I see the set-cookie header via postman but not in my front end React app?

Happy to post more code snippets if need be.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Stuck at the same issue. Kindly update when you figure this out :) Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

`herokuapp.app` is listed in `Public suffix` List which means cookies are blocked from bein set to the domain `"herokuapp.com"`

you must use custom domain technique

Comment: @cfree @ PrateekThakur

Answer (score 0):

Stuck with this issue for some time. What I figured out:

1. Need add proxy attribute to app:

```
const app = new Koa()
app.proxy = true
```

2. Extend cookies options with sameSite attribute:

```
cookies.set("accessToken", token, {
  maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 24,
  signed: true,
  secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
  httpOnly: true,
  domain: process.env.ORIGIN_HOSTNAME || "localhost",
  sameSite: 'none' // <-- add this
})
```

Before that I bought a domain for my app. Frontend app point to "domain.com", and Backend app point to "api.domain.com". But now I am not sure if it was necessary.